# Connecting C# to MYSQL database?

Tags: c#, mysql

So i been trying to connect C# windows from to MYSQL database, i tryed many different methods that i found online but none seems to be working. here is my code please help (keep in mind this is the first time i use database before).

Here is the connecting class

```
class DbConnect
{
    public static void DBConnect()
    {
        string connstr = 
        "server=localhost;user=root;database=login;port=3306;password=Password";

        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connstr);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("went rong");
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the windows form im using

```
private void btnenter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      DbConnect.DBConnect();
      MySqlCommand query = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO logininfo (username, 
      password) VALUES(@username, @password");
        try
        {
            query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtusername.Text);
            query.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("S");
        }

        catch (Exception )
        {
            MessageBox.Show("something went wrong");
        }
        finally
        {
            DbConnect.DBClose();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Don't you have to assign the connection to the `MySqlCommand` object?

Comment: Show us what you tried so far and what specific problems you encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem you have here is you're not setting the Connection property of your  MysqlCommand to the MySqlConnection you're making earlier.

1. Change DBConnect() to return your MySqlConnection.
2. Set your MySqlCommand's Connection property to the returned value.

PSEUDO-CODE

```
MySqlConnection conn = DBConnect.DBConnect();
 MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(commandStr, conn);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: What type of return does it need, just a boolean?

Comment: No, it should return a MySqlConnection object (specifically your conn instance.)

Answer (score 2):

User is passed in MySQL connection string using `Uid`. So your connection string should be like:

```
"server=localhost;Uid=root;database=login;port=3306;password=tro63jans";
```

You may see: [MySQL connection string.](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/)

You should also catch exception in some object, so that you can get the details about the exception. Currently you are not showing any useful message from your exception.

```
catch (Exception ex) //at least
{
    MessageBox.Show("something went wrong: " + ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Ok so i changes the uid and still did not work, im making the exception now to see what else is wrong

Comment: Connection must be vail and open is what its saying, so something is wrong with the connection